# Из серии замыкания в PHP, мозгошторм

Tags: php

Помогите докумекать

Есть вот такой вот код (часть класса)

```
protected $q;

public function query($query) {
    $this->q=$this->db->query($query);
    return $this->q;
}

public function fetch_object() {
    if(!is_object($this->q)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->q->fetchObject();
}
```

Вот так используется и все работает нормально

```
if($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `blog`;") {
    while($row = $this->db->fetch_object()) {

    }
}
```

Но если сделать вложенность, то ничего работать не будет

```
if($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `blog`;") {
    while($row = $this->db->fetch_object()) {
        if($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `comment`;") {
            while($row_x = $this->db->fetch_object()) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Все дело в `$this->db->q` в которой сохраняется ссылка на обьек

В общем нужно как то применив замыкание сделать `$this->q` для каждого вызова функции `query` свою

Comment: так пусть метод query возвращает объект, у которого уже и будет вызываться fetch_object. А внутрь this пусть ничего не сохраняет.

А замыкания... думаю они не помогут здесь.

P.S. Глядя на код, я уже понимаю, почему портилась база:)

Comment: нет :) база портилась потому что часто отказывал сервер

этот код написал только что в качестве примера, если не сохранять ничего внутри $this то и смысла нет ничего менять так как именно так работает pdo

если бы это был бы javascript вопросов бы не возникало, тут же я пока не догоняю с какого боку подойти

Comment: Так может и использовать pdo? или есть желание построить велосипедики с гусеницами?

Comment: @fffffffggggggggg, Вы бы ник сменили....

Вообще-то Вам нужно, чтобы `q` было  стеком, а не элементарной переменной. Каждый вызов `query()` делает *`push`*. А вот *`pop`*, видимо проще ручками.